# Add Address Book Framework for iOS 8 with Xcode8

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode8, abaddressbook

I am working on application in which I need to support iOS 8 onwards devices. Application used iOS contacts So I need to add both `ABAddress` and `contacts framework`. 
I am facing a strange problem with Xcode 8 that `ABAddressFramework` not found at run time and application crashed.
I have added the framework in **Link Binary With Library** with required tag.
Please provide your input on this.

Comment: Can you write some code here you are using for this?

Comment: Privacy - Contacts Usage Description    Are you adding this in your info.plist?

Comment: @SNarula I have already added that.

Comment: Please write code here.

Comment: Hi @SNarula, There is no specific code just try to access "kABPersonAddressZIPKey" constant in app launch and app will crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I resolved the issue and I tried removing and adding the ABAdressFramework  and it works. I think Order is also playing important role:

https://github.com/OceanLabs/iOS-Print-SDK/issues/257[image]